# IMAP server response

Tags: php, sockets, imap

I'm developing my own webmail, I'm using socket (PHP) to get the body of an email, I get an answer from the server:

> ```
> * 1 EXISTS 
> * 0 RECENT 
> * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1398151393] 
> * OK [UIDNEXT 15] 
> ? OK [READ-WRITE] Completed 
> * 1 FETCH (BODY [TEXT] {12}
>
> Here is the message 
>
> )
> ```

How can I removed the extra lines to be answered only the body of the email?

Comment: Either your formatting is not correct, or your question is not clear. What do you mean, by wanting to remove extra lines to be answered?

Comment: after connecting to the imap server ($soc = fsockopen('192.168.56.101',143);) and login ($request = fputs($stuff,"? LOGIN example@example.br 12345\r\n");)

Comment: $soc = fsockopen('192.168.56.101',143);                         $request = fputs($stuff,"? LOGIN example@example.br 12345\r\n");          $request = fputs($stuff,"? SELECT INBOX\r\n");                 $request = fputs($stuff,"? FETCH 1 BODY[TEXT]\r\n");                                        i get as respond from the server                                    * 1 EXISTS 
* 0 RECENT 
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1398151393] 
* OK [UIDNEXT 15] 
? OK [READ-WRITE] Completed 
* 1 FETCH (BODY [TEXT] {12}

Here is the message 
  
)  what i have to do to get only the body of the email??

Comment: ^ Can you edit those lines into your post, OP? I don't know if they will help, but they will be a great deal more readable in the question, as long as you use the formatting tools.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you have not read the [IMAP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) yet.  Have a look at [Section 2.2 Commands and Responses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-2.2) in particular.

You are sending multiple requests (and *not* tagging them uniquely like you are supposed to!) before then reading the replies.

The first 5 lines:

```
* 1 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1398151393] 
* OK [UIDNEXT 15] 
? OK [READ-WRITE] Completed
```

All belong to the reply to your [`SELECT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.3.1) command. The first 4 lines are *untagged responses* describing various aspects of the mailbox you have selected.  The 5th line is a *tagged response* as it is prefixed with the same tag that you specified in the [`SELECT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.3.1) command (`?`) and thus ends the reply.  Until you receive that *tagged response*, you have to keep reading lines and processing them as needed.

The remaining lines you showed:

```
* 1 FETCH (BODY [TEXT] {12}

Here is the message 

)
```

All belong to the reply to your [`FETCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5) command.  Again, until you receive the final *tagged response* (which you did not show), you have to keep reading and processing lines as needed in order to capture what you are looking for.  In this case, there is an added complexity.  This reply contains a *string literal* (see [Section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-4.3)).  The `{12}` is the string's octet length, followed by a CRLF, followed by exactly 12 octets of character data.  So you have to watch for that and process accordingly whenever you encounter it.

You cannot just ignore arbitrary lines, you have to look at each one and act accordingly.  They have context and meaning.  Try something more like this instead:

```
$soc = fsockopen('192.168.56.101',143);

$request = fputs($soc,"A1 LOGIN example@example.br 12345\r\n");
// read until you receive a reply tagged with A1,
// processing any untagged responses accordingly

$request = fputs($soc,"A2 SELECT INBOX\r\n");
// read until you receive a reply tagged with A2,
// processing any untagged responses accordingly

$request = fputs($soc,"A3 FETCH 1 BODY[TEXT]\r\n");
// read until you receive a reply tagged with A3,
// processing any untagged responses accordingly
```

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer. Just one thing - I suggest you refer to RFC3501 rather than RFC1730 (unless PHP uses an old version of IMAP).

Comment: @Gigi: In this situation it doesn't matter what PHP supports since it is not the one implementing IMAP to begin with. However, it would be worthwhile to try finding a pre-made PHP-based IMAP client instead of implementing IMAP by hand. IMAP has a lot of complexities.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the liberty of pasting OP's comment into an answer for readability:

```
$soc = fsockopen('192.168.56.101',143);
$request = fputs($stuff,"? LOGIN example@example.br 12345\r\n"); 
$request = fputs($stuff,"? SELECT INBOX\r\n");
$request = fputs($stuff,"? FETCH 1 BODY[TEXT]\r\n");
```

> i get as respond from the server:

```
* 1 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1398151393]
* OK [UIDNEXT 15]
? OK [READ-WRITE] Completed
* 1 FETCH (BODY [TEXT] {12} Here is the message )
```

> what i have to do to get only the body of the email??

If I'm reading this right, OP is using "?" for the tag of all their requests.